# MySQL Historical timeline

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I Would like create a historical data within timestamp over MySQL:

Example status table:

```
ticket_id       status      created
1               created     11/11/2021
1               review      11/12/2021
1               completed   11/13/2021
2               created     11/11/2021
2               review      11/12/2021
2               completed   11/13/2021
```

and my expected result is:

```
ticket id   created     review      completed   latest_status
1           11/11/2021  11/12/2021  11/13/2021  completed
2           11/11/2021  11/12/2021  11/13/2021  completed
```

Already tried using case when and max or min, but some timestamp not appeared. Anyone have any suggestion for this?

Using pivot with max case I got the following:

```
ticket id   created     review      completed   latest_status
1                                   11/13/2021  completed
2                                   11/13/2021  completed
```

Thanks in advanced

Comment: I tried that before, but if the current status used (max) of the ticket is completed, created and review timestamp return empty :(

Comment: Solved, creating subquery